# symlink to newrelic.so into php modules in OpenShift

Tags: php, openshift, newrelic

I am trying to "install" new relic agent into my OpenShift website.

this has php-5.4 cartridge and a joomla that I found earlier (around 5 months ago) and now I wish to check metrics with New Relic.

I know superuser here is disabled and some folders -included php modules- has root as user:group so I would want to know if exists an alternative to make a symlink (ln) to newrelic.so into that folder or if is possible to include another folder for more php modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably something to ask OpenShift about. Since they manage the platform, they'd have a better understanding on how to get this set up according to their particular distribution, automated application setups, etc.

Comment: yeah, but they remit since some months ago to StackOverflow for any question. I don't remember but I am a quite sure about adding an extra path to php extensions in a config file but I don't remember where.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't have the permissions to install custom php extensions with the php-5.4 cartridge: You'll have to create a do-it-yourself cartridge and install php by yourself to be able to link and configure the New Relic extension.

I've created a cartridge for this purpose to get you started:

https://github.com/sebastien-fauvel/openshift-newrelic-php

You'll have to create a new Openshift app based on this cartridge, to install Joomla manually there, to migrate your app code and your data, and to switch your domain aliases to the new node when you're ready. A bit of work, but it's definitely worth it!

Comment: OK thank you but I've create a DIY app with the same result. I've just tried that cartridge and when I checked newrelic was not installed and checking one of the issues is trying to make a symlink into php extension. 

Just used your cartridge to do it with that result.

Comment: Hi @Sébastien Fauvel I have cloned again your cartridge and finally it works. a question: having an existing non-diy app could I to try to make same push -deleting before php-5.4 cartridge-?